# PHP (AuraPHP router) - routing with more than one optional parameters

Tags: router, auraphp

i have got a little problem in my auraphp router. For example i have this URL : oleje/134/motorove-oleje-pro-automobily/

But i can have this URl also : oleje/134/motorove-oleje-pro-automobily/oleje-shell

The "oleje-shell" part of URL is optional and i need to put behind this part one more optional parameter called "per_page". So i need something like : oleje/134/motorove-oleje-pro-automobily/35 or : oleje/134/motorove-oleje-pro-automobily/oleje-shell/35.

I hope, you got it.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options are coming to my mind.

1. [Optional Params](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Router/#optional-params)

   $router->add('archive', '/oleje/134/motorove-oleje-pro-automobily{/oleje,number}');
2. [Wild card Params](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Router/#wildcard-params)

   $router->add('wild_post', '/oleje/134/motorove-oleje-pro-automobily/')
       ->setWildcard('other');

   // this matches, with the following values
   $route = $router->match('/oleje/134/motorove-oleje-pro-automobily/oleje-shell/35', $_SERVER);
   // $route->params['other'] = array('oleje-shell', '35')

In both cases you may want to check whether the one you got is string or number.

Hope that help!